# MySQL - Left Join with Case select sets NULL value in first CASE

Tags: mysql

### Scenario

I have a users table that has a column for the users iso_code_2 for their country of residence and nationality, and in another table I have all the countries in different languages, so what I want to do is get the country text for the users residence and nationality. I know the problem is the `GROUP BY` but I do not know how to solve it.

### Tables

```
/* Users table */
╔══════╦═════════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╗
║  id  ║  firstname  ║  lastname  ║  residence  ║  nationality  ║
╚══════╩═════════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╝
│  1   │     Joe     │    Doe     │     JP      │      PH       │
├──────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────────┼───────────────┤
│  2   │    Lisa     │  Simpson   │     US      │      AR       │
├──────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────────┼───────────────┤
│  3   │    Homer    │  Simpson   │     JP      │      JP       │
└──────┴─────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴───────────────┘

/* Countries table */
╔══════╦═══════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║  id  ║  language_id  ║  iso_code_2  ║       country       ║
╚══════╩═══════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════╝
│  1   │       1       │      JP      │        Japan        │
├──────┼───────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│  2   │       2       │      JP      │         日本        │
├──────┼───────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│  3   │       1       │      PH      │     Philippines     │
├──────┼───────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│  4   │       2       │      PH      │       フィリピン     │
├──────┼───────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│  5   │       1       │      US      │    United States    │
├──────┼───────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│  6   │       2       │      US      │         米国        │
├──────┼───────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│  7   │       1       │      AR      │      Argentina      │
├──────┼───────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│  8   │       2       │      AR      │     アルゼンチン     │
└──────┴───────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────┘

/* Expected results */
╔══════╦═════════════╦════════════╦════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║  id  ║  firstname  ║  lastname  ║    residence_country   ║  nationality_country  ║
╚══════╩═════════════╩════════════╩════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
│  1   │     Joe     │    Doe     │         Japan          │      Philippines      │
├──────┼─────────────┼────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│  1   │    Lisa     │  Simpson   │      United States     │       Argentina       │
├──────┼─────────────┼────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│  1   │    Homer    │  Simpson   │         Japan          │         Japan         │
└──────┴─────────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

### Current Query

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname,
    CASE c.iso_code_2
        WHEN u.nationality THEN c.country
    END AS nationality_country,
    CASE c.iso_code_2
        WHEN u.residence THEN c.country
    END AS residence_country
FROM
    users AS u
        LEFT JOIN
    countries AS c ON c.language_id = 1 WHERE c.iso_code_2 IN (u.nationality, u.residence)
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.created_at DESC
LIMIT 15
```

### Wrong results

```
╔══════╦═════════════╦════════════╦════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║  id  ║  firstname  ║  lastname  ║    residence_country   ║  nationality_country  ║
╚══════╩═════════════╩════════════╩════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
│  1   │     Joe     │    Doe     │         NULL           │      Philippines      │
├──────┼─────────────┼────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│  1   │    Lisa     │  Simpson   │         NULL           │       Argentina       │
├──────┼─────────────┼────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│  1   │    Homer    │  Simpson   │         NULL           │         Japan         │
└──────┴─────────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Comment: One of your `CASE` statements don't seem to be for a column that exists in the `users` table: `WHEN u.residence_country THEN c.country`

Comment: @Dez Sorry about that, it was a typo when building the question, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You group by is retaining only one row per user in the result. Depending on MySQL's preferences, it will either contain the residence_country or the nationality_country.

You need to select twice from the country table to get your desired results *(and it will make the query easier)*

```
 SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname,
    cn.country
    cr.country
FROM
    users AS u
    LEFT JOIN countries AS cn ON cn.language_id = 1 WHERE cn.iso_code_2 = u.nationality
    LEFT JOIN countries AS cr ON cr.language_id = 1 WHERE cr.iso_code_2 = u.residence
```

Comment: I thought on doing this, but why make 2 joins to the same table, when it can be done in one, I just find it inefficient.

Comment: The optimizer would disagree with that but if you insist, you can add a MIN or MAX to the case to make it work as you wrote it.